# maximal torus and semisimple elements

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

I am being stupid here. $G$ is a connected algebraic group and $s$ is a semisimple element. Let $T$ be a maximal torus. Then if $T$ is contained in $C_G(s)$, then $s$ is in $T$. I got stuck here. I know semisimple elements are in maximal tori. But here, could $s$ be in a different torus $T'$ conjugate to $T$? I am trying to show the two tori are in fact one.

This question is from P112 of Gunter Malle's "linear algebraic group and finite group of Lie type".

Proposition 14.1) Let $G$ be connected, $s ∈ G$ semisimple, $T ≤ G$ a maximal torus. Then $s ∈ T$ if and only if $T ≤ C_G(s)^◦$. In particular, $s ∈ C_G(s)^◦$.

Proof: As $T$ is abelian, $s ∈ T$ if and only if $T ≤ C_G(s)$, which is equivalent to $T ≤ C_G(s)^◦$ as $T$ is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're getting at, but I think it seems like maybe you want the following:

> **Fact:** Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over a field $F$ and
> let $s\in G(F)$ be semisimple. Then, for a maximal torus $T$ of $G$
> the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $s\in T(F)$.
> 2. $T$ is a maximal torus of $C_G(s)^\circ$.

*Proof:* If $s\in T(F)$ then since $T$ is abelian we know that $T$ centralizes $s$ and thus $T\subseteq C_G(s)$. Since $T$ is connected we then also have that $T\subseteq C_G(s)^\circ$.

*Remark:* Note that the above argument also shows, since every semisimple element of $G(F)$ is in $T(F)$ for some maximal torus $T$ of $G$, that $s\in C_G(s)^\circ$ (it's obvious that $s\in C_G(s)$, but less obvious it's in $C_G(s)^\circ$).

Conversely, suppose that $T$ is a maximal torus of $C_G(s)^\circ$. Since $C_G(s)^\circ$ is reductive (e.g. see [Humphreys, Theorem in §2.2]--it's easy to reduce to the semisimple case) we know that $Z(C_G(s))\subseteq T$ (e.g. see [Milne, Proposition 21.7]). But, since $s\in Z(C_G(s))(F)$ this implies that $s\in T(F)$. $\blacksquare$

**References:**

[Humphreys] Humphreys, J.E., 2011. Conjugacy classes in semisimple algebraic groups (No. 43). American Mathematical Soc..

[Milne] Milne, J.S., 2017. Algebraic groups: The theory of group schemes of finite type over a field (Vol. 170). Cambridge University Press.

Comment: thx for your input! I edited my question. In this proposition, it didn't mention reductiveness, which drives me crazy. And I got stuck at one direction.

Comment: any further comments would be appreciated！

Comment: @gerrard I mean this is false as stated. Let $G=\mathbb{G}_a$ and let $s\in \mathbb{G}_a(F)$ be any element. Then, the maximal tori of $G$ are trivial and so ar contained in $C_G(s)^\circ$, but evidently $s$ is not in $T(F)$ if $s$ is non-trivial. You need reductive hypotheses.

Comment: In your proof, you don't need the assumption that $s$ is semi-simple, right? Moreover, for the converse part of your proof, I think it can be simpler. If $T\subset C_G(s)^\circ$, then $T\subset C_G(s)$, so $Z(C_G(s))\subset Z(T)$. Moreover, since $T$ is a maximal torus in a connected reductive group, so $Z(T)=T$. Hence $s\in Z(C_G(s))\subset T$.